# Listening to music during the 3 weeks?

Tags: halacha, music, three-weeks, leniencies

There are many types of music which some authorities permit listening to during the Omer:

1. Rav Shlomo Zalman allows classical music and chazannus. (Halichas Shlomo)
2. The Chelkas Yakov allows recorded music. (1:62)  I have also heard this in the name of Rav Hutner.
3. The Sefer Eleh Haim Moadai permits music while driving (where one cannot dance)

[my thanks to Rav Enkin for the sources]

I have seen these heterim quoted by many people and relied upon in many circles.

Do they also apply to the 3 weeks? What are the factors involved? Is the prohibition against listening to music more stringent during the three weeks than during the Omer?

Comment: Three weeks are more stringent

Comment: Regarding three weeks Rav Shlomo Zalman wasn't so clear if chazzanos is problematic,but recorded music was.Shalmei Moed pg.478,see also Kovetz Halachos perek 4:4 which talks about all inyanim and all types of music,the bottom line is wether it brings simcha